# Linux Voyager Desktop clock bug

Tags: desktop, clock

[image: Desktop Clock]

Hello everyone , as you can see I have a problem with the desktop clock , I tried switching main language and it didn't work . I couldn't find any other forums with the same problem either . I am not very experienced with GNU/Linux but I love some distros !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I know nothing about this program, but when characters appear as boxes like this, it's usually a font or encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings -> Language Support -> Regional Formats, select proper format.
the change needs re-login.